# COD only for a particular city in a country how to write the csv file in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, cash-on-delivery

I am using magento 1.9. And I want to set no cod for a country except for a city/state in that country.I'm stuck with creating the csv file. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any custom extension for this ?

Comment: How you are creating csv ? which module/code you are using for this?

Comment: may be [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392323/magentohow-to-enable-disable-cod-based-on-city-and-not-on-countries) helps, if you tie up with any `shipping logistics team` , if you get the list of zip codes , than it will be easy for you......

Answer (score 0):

You may create a csv file with these columns

```
Country  State  COD_Available
```

store yes/no to COD_Available column and then you will have to hook an event which is something like "payment method is active" and in that event you may disable the COD payment method on the basis of the shipping address of the order.